# Code doesn't print the correct number of repeated digits

Tags: java

So basically this is a method to print numbers from `0` to `n` but squared. And to return the number of digits "d" contained in the numbers from `0` to `n`.

So let's say `n=10` and `d=1`, we will have `0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100` and the method should return `4` since there are `4` ones in this set of numbers.

This works fine, but when `n` is defined with a bigger integer that's where the method starts to return an incorrect number of digits.

for instance, if we have `n=5750` and `d=0`, the method returns `3012` when it's supposed to return `4700`. Where did I do wrong?

```
public static int numberOfDig(int n, int d) {
        String output="";
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
            output+=(int)Math.pow(i, 2)+" ";
        }


        String[] numbers=output.split(" ");
        String digit= Integer.toString(d);
        int count =0;

        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            if(numbers[i].contains(digit))count++;
        }

        return count;
}
```

Please don't hesitate to ask questions if you need further explanations.

Comment: First question: what debugging have you attempted?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you only increment your count by one when a number contains the digit `d`. You need to increment by the number of times `d` occurs in each number.

The relevant code is:

```
if (numbers[i].contains(digit))
    count++;
```

So if `d == 5` and `numbers[i] == 25`, you increment `count` by `1` which is correct.

However, if `d == 0` and `numbers[i] == 100` you increment `count` by 1 which is incorrect. You should increment by 2 (as there are two zeroes).

A simple test would be `n=10` and `d=1`, where `output` will be `0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121`. Your method will return `5` as there are five numbers that contain a `1`, whereas it should return `6` as `121` contains two instances of `1`.

Comment: It should actually return 4 since n goes from 0 to 10 not 0 to 11. And it counts double digits in the same number because when n=11 and d=1 it returns 5 counting the two ones in the 121. I just tried it

Comment: @BlueEagle Your loop runs from [0..n] inclusive because you have `i<=n` not `i<n`, so if `n==11`, it will run from 0 to 11. I did make a mistake though. There are five numbers with a 1 (not four) in them and the answer should be 6 in this case, not 5. I've run your code now and this is the bug.